# OpenGLRenderer: Path too large to be rendered into a texture in Titanium

Tags: android, imageview, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I have this error in an Android app only in tablets, one image (ImageView) doesn't appear and Appcelerator shows this error:

> "OpenGLRenderer: Path too large to be rendered into a texture"

In the other devices all works fine. I don't understand this error because the image has space to appear. At phones and iPads it works perfectly.

I'm using width: {'100%', height: 'auto'} for this ImageView, because the width and height of his parent view change depending on the screen size. I'm working with %.

I tried this:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="false"/>
```

at manifest but the problem still happening.

Please, help me.

The red square is the image that doesn't appear. It's same width and height than the blue square.

[image]

This is the image that is missing:
[image]

The code:

- Tss file : http://pastebin.com/akEEa6Tb
- View file: http://pastebin.com/TcakniAn
- Controller file: http://pastebin.com/36bQrywn

> Operating System   Name                        = Mac OS X   Version
>   = 10.11.1   Architecture                = 64bit   # CPUs                      = 8   Memory                      = 4294967296 Node.js   Node.js Version             = 0.12.7   npm Version                 = 2.11.3
>   Titanium CLI   CLI Version                 = 5.0.5 Titanium SDK   SDK
>   Version                 = 5.0.2.GA   SDK Path                    =
>   /Users/a/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.0.2.GA
>   Target Platform             = android

Comment: Could you attach the actual image?

Comment: this is the actual image. This is my result. Do you need more info?

Comment: The red square doesn't appear, I put it for the explanation. The blue, orange and yellow are my result.

Comment: You say "one image (ImageView) doesn't appear" so I wonder if you could upload that image so we can see if there's something odd with it.

Comment: I attach it, is the green square.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I think this problem is a bug in Android, because in other controller I have the same problem and it's a more simple screen. Please review this, is important

Comment: Well, that image seems allright. Could you provide the full test case? A project with this view that fails for you? Plus the SDK version and other environment info so I can try to reproduce?

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I've found this thread https://community.appcelerator.com/topic/3103/dynamic-styles-layout-and-android/2 it seems the same problem. But it doesn't have solution yet.

Comment: That Q&A topic seems to be about positioning, not about loading an image or not. Again. If you have a test case I can reproduce then I'd be happy to help you find the issue.

Comment: @FokkeZandbergen I think the problem is that layout: 'horizontal' in Android. If I put de green image at the blue position it appears perfectly. And if I put the blue image into de green position, the blue image doesn't appear. The code is my test code. If you load the view you can see the problem

Comment: Maybe what you are seeing is https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-19900. Unfortunately I don't have time to dive into debugging your actual source code atm. I must say it does seem over-complex too me and also hard to read with all those nested views and numbered classes/ids.

Comment: ok, thank you.Working with Titanium... big problem.

Comment: I get the same problem drawing a path on Mapbox map. The solution is to disable hardware acceleration... :'(